# Does a logical partition scan in CosmosDB always returns items in the same order?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, partitioning

In CosmosDB using the SQL API ( hope API might not matter ) and queries that do not use `ORDER BY` over an specific Logic Partition ( e.g. `WHERE CustomerId = 123` ), wondering if the response will return the results **always in the same order**.

A use case could be something like an Audit log, where it is possible that TimeStamp `_ts` is not granular enough so likely to find at some point the same value twice and the source or events doesn't allow to create an sequence that can be used for ordering.

Answer (score 0):

> wondering if the response will return the results always in the same
>   order.

Based on my previous test, if you do not set any sort rules, it will be sorted as default based on the time created in the database,whatever it is partitioned or not.

[image]

In above sample documents, the sort will not be changed if I change the id,partition key(that's name) or ts.

Comment: In a few tests I have tried it returns in the same order, but not sure if there is something that can officially indicate that is is going to be always the case. In addition of a few test in Azure, i did also used the emulator and inserted lost of records in several partitions and at the moment seems ok, but possibly I haven't tried enough.

Comment: @jleyva Hi,if my answer helps you,would you please mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.

Comment: The evidence provided is not conclusive, Relying on this behaviour might not be a big issue for a log. Unfortunately, even if the current implementation returns the records in the same order, nothing guarantees that future version will change the behaviour as there is no official statement of how it should behave. In case strict order is required is better to include an order clause. I was hoping that was not necessary.